# Plugins breaking vim mappings?

Tags: vim, plugins, macvim

I just installed DelimitMate and CloseTag plugins for MacVim and they seem to have broken these two mapping in my .vimrc:

```
"F7 WordProcessorOn  

:map <leader>w :set linebreak <CR> :set display+=lastline <CR> :set wrap <CR> :setlocal spell spelllang=en_gb <CR>

"F8 WordProcessorOff  

:map <leader>c :set nowrap <CR> :set nospell <CR>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem could be? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out what is 'hijacking' the mappings by doing

```
:verbose map <leader>c
:verbose map <F8>
```

etc.

But likely your problem is with submappings firing: use

```
:noremap <leader>c .......
```

to prevent remapping

**PS**: consider mapping for specific modes (`nnoremap` over `noremap`); Being explicit avoids funny interfering mappings a lot of the time

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I also appreciate the helpful suggestions about using `:verbose` and `nnoremap`.